# Is there a client side work-around for a too-short auto logout from an SSH connection?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sshd, logout

I SSH from one Linux host to another Linux host that I don't administer.  Its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is apparently configured to auto-logout after an interval of inactivity that is too brief for my taste ([How do I enable auto-logout of Interactive ssh logins after one hour](https://superuser.com/questions/656021/how-do-i-enable-auto-logout-of-interactive-ssh-logins-after-one-hour)).

Is there any way to keep my SSH session alive, perhaps by sending or receiving a newline character every two minutes?

Workarounds like `while true { echo ' '; sleep 120 }` were common in the days of dialup modems).

FWIW, Windows' PuTTY isn't involved at all.

Comment: Is it bash's TMOUT, or ssh?

Comment: Well, ssh to other hosts doesn't time out.  And $TMOUT isn't defined.

Comment: Hm, that led me to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222283/read-only-tmout-variable-workaround-to-disable-automatically-exit-shell-when-t .  Post something like that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it bash's TMOUT, or ssh?  If it's TMOUT, there are a couple options
listed here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675598/getting-kicked-out-of-openshift-server-after-a-while/25689720#25689720

Or
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222283/read-only-tmout-variable-workaround-to-disable-automatically-exit-shell-when-t

-Erik

Comment: It's ssh, not TMOUT.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to `$HOME/.ssh/config` on the SSH client side:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Adjust the interval (60) to whatever works for your situation. See t[he man pages for details](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In bash: `while sleep 120; do printf '\33[0n'; done`.

*Edit:* This emits an invisible string every two minutes. Those characters sent to the terminal are enough to fool whatever is looking for inactivity on the ssh session.

To stop this and get a bash prompt again, just hit Ctrl+C.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Could you add a sentence or two to explain what this does?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `sshd_config` file. 
In my case it was on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

was:

```
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

to:

```
ClientAliveInterval 6000
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

Don’t forget

```
service sshd restart
```

Comment: This answers a different question.  The original question is about what to do when you *can't* change the target host's configuration.