# Configure OpenSSH to disconnect idle SFTP clients

Tags: ssh, openssh, sftp

How to configure `sftp-server` subsystem specified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to disconnect idle SFTP clients.

Neither [`sshd_config` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5) nor nor the [`sftp-server` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server.8) have info to configure such parameter for the subsystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until OpenSSH 8.2, you could abuse [`ClientAliveInterval`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveInterval) and [`ClientAliveCountMax 0`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveCountMax) to disconnect idle clients:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

But this has been [declared as a bug in 8.2](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2627) and is no longer working. Since 8.2, there's no way to disconnect the idle clients, only unresponsive clients.

---

I believe these days, most OpenSSH installations are still pre-8.2, so you might still be able to use this. But it may stop working after upgrade one day.

---

As @KamilMaciorowski suggested in a comment, a clever wrapper (script) over the `sftp-server` executable would do too. It won't even be difficult. It would ignore SSH keepalives though (what some may like, some not). And it will need the `sftp-server` binary (instead of the default `internal-sftp`), what makes it complicated to chroot the session